# Pros and Cons of using a non-pointer class object

Tags: pointer

In this example I have an one object which uses a pointer and one object which does not.

```
class MyClass {
  public:
    void myMethod() {
      // do nothing
    }
};

MyClass* mc1;
MyClass mc2;

void setup() {
  mc1 = new MyClass();
}

void loop() {
  mc1->myMethod();
  mc2.myMethod();
}
```

Is one implementation better than the other? Why?

Comment: Are you looking for an answer from an Arduino/small scale embedded programming perspective or general C++. "new" implies using a heap and pointers implies using indirection (which is slower but may be used for dynamic binding, e.g. redirecting mc1 during the execution of the program to another instance such as mc2; "mc1 = &mc2").

Comment: @MikaelPatel That's a tough one. I would love to hear both sides if you have the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this situation, where you are just working with globals, the static declaration is preferred, although it makes little difference.

The static declaration (`MyClass mc2`) will reserve space in the BSS. The dynamic allocation (`mc1 = new MyClass()`) will allocate space on the heap at run time at the start of your sketch. Both are in pretty much the same area of RAM (the heap is directly above the static data area).

The only trouble starts to come when you want to free (`delete`) the object created with `new`. That can, over time, make a complete swiss-cheese mess of your heap which can cause memory allocation problems.

For that reason the dynamic method is shunned, but if all you ever do is allocate at the start and never deallocate then there is little practical difference between the two methods.

Comment: Fortunately I'm familiar with C style garbage collection as wall as ObjC retain/release. I assumed Arduino followed a similar suit so thank you for pointing out the effects of allocation.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to do and partly a matter of taste but I tend to take this one step further when the class corresponds to a specific hardware resource. In this case you can use static methods exclusively to guarantee a 1 to 1 correspondence. Templates come to rescue when you want to bind a specific physical instance of some finite resource (e.g. one of the timers) and this can be further refined using specialization and traits (each timer has different characteristics).